# Custom menu items are not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need the menu items to look like they are now (like in iOS), but so far I have two big problems.
First, when I try to click on one of the links, it's not possible because of my linear-gradient. And second, when I click the down arrow to explore other menu items, all the gradient does not work.
How can I make it work properly?

I have also made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/ibrahim-kunushefci/pen/ExYBRba) for this

```js
 document.querySelectorAll('.slide').forEach(function (next) {
   next.addEventListener('click', function () {
     var container = this.parentElement.querySelector('.select');
     sideScroll(container, 'bottom', 20, 25, 15);
   });
 });

document.querySelectorAll('.slideBack').forEach(function (back) {
  back.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var container = this.parentElement.querySelector('.select');
    sideScroll(container, 'top', 20, 25, 15);
  });
});

function sideScroll(element, direction, speed, distance, step) {
  scrollAmount = 0;
  var slideTimer = setInterval(function () {
    if (direction == 'top') {
      element.scrollTop -= step;
    } else {
      element.scrollTop += step;
    }
    scrollAmount += step;
    if (scrollAmount >= distance) {
      window.clearInterval(slideTimer);
    }
  }, speed);
}
```

```css
* {
  background: #80acdc;
}
.larger {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
 .larger .select {
  width: 240px;
  height: 270px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-style: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  position: relative;
}
 .larger .select::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#80acdc, transparent, #80acdc);
}
 .larger .select a {
  color: white;
  margin: 3.5px 0;
}
 .larger .select a:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
 .larger #slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 47%;
  bottom: 38px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
 .larger #slideBack {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: 47%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="larger">
        <div class="select">
          <a href="#">Action Lorem </a>
          <a href="#">Test Text</a>
          <a href="#">Action Lorem</a>
          <a href="#">Test Text</a>
          <a href="#">Action Lorem</a>
          <a href="#">Test Text</a>
          <a href="#">Action Lorem</a>
          <a href="#">Test Text</a>
          <a href="#">Action Lorem</a>
          <a href="#">Test Text</a>
          <a href="#">Action Lorem</a>
          <a href="#">Test Text</a>
          <a href="#">Action Lorem</a>
          <a href="#">Test Text</a>
          <a href="#">Action Lorem</a>
          <a href="#">Test Text</a>
        </div>
        <i id="slideBack" class="slideBack fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
        <i id="slide" class="slide fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you actually using jQuery (as per your question tags)?

Comment: You're probably better off searching for a plugin to imitate the iOS functionality as it's more complex than it appears. For example, you can scroll all the way to the top/bottom (e.g. https://i.imgur.com/Tt7wF6K.png) which means it's not always a `100% -> 0% -> 100%` gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the gradient to allow interaction with the underling elements you can use `pointer-events: none`
2. Your gradient is absolute positioned with `top: 0` so it goes together with the scroll. In order to fix this you can set the position of the gradient to `fixed` (but then it will be stretched to the sizes of the vewport). The better way would be to wrap the list of the options with another container so the scroll won't influence the gradient position.. Something like this:

```html
<div class="select-wrap">
  <div class="select">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.larger .select-wrap {
  width: 240px;
  height: 270px;
}

.larger .select-wrap .select {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-style: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  position: relative;
}

.larger .select-wrap::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#80acdc, transparent, #80acdc);
  pointer-events: none; /* this allows for the mouse clicks go through */
}
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.slide').forEach(function(next) {
  next.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var container = this.parentElement.querySelector('.select');
    sideScroll(container, 'bottom', 20, 25, 15);
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll('.slideBack').forEach(function(back) {
  back.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var container = this.parentElement.querySelector('.select');
    sideScroll(container, 'top', 20, 25, 15);
  });
});

function sideScroll(element, direction, speed, distance, step) {
  scrollAmount = 0;
  var slideTimer = setInterval(function() {
    if (direction == 'top') {
      element.scrollTop -= step;
    } else {
      element.scrollTop += step;
    }
    scrollAmount += step;
    if (scrollAmount >= distance) {
      window.clearInterval(slideTimer);
    }
  }, speed);
}
```

```css
* {
  background: #80acdc;
}

.larger {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.larger .select-wrap {
  width: 240px;
  height: 270px;
}

.larger .select-wrap .select {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-style: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  position: relative;
}

.larger .select-wrap::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#80acdc, transparent, #80acdc);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.larger .select a {
  color: white;
  margin: 3.5px 0;
}

.larger .select a:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.larger #slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 47%;
  bottom: 38px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.larger #slideBack {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: 47%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="larger">
        <div class="select-wrap">
          <div class="select">
            <a href="#">Action Lorem </a>
            <a href="#">Test Text</a>
            <a href="#">Action Lorem</a>
            <a href="#">Test Text</a>
            <a href="#">Action Lorem</a>
            <a href="#">Test Text</a>
            <a href="#">Action Lorem</a>
            <a href="#">Test Text</a>
            <a href="#">Action Lorem</a>
            <a href="#">Test Text</a>
            <a href="#">Action Lorem</a>
            <a href="#">Test Text</a>
            <a href="#">Action Lorem</a>
            <a href="#">Test Text</a>
            <a href="#">Action Lorem</a>
            <a href="#">Test Text</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <i id="slideBack" class="slideBack fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
        <i id="slide" class="slide fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```